# Simulating variable column names in sqlite

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite, entity-attribute-value

I want to store entries (a set of key=>value pairs) in a database, but the keys vary from entry to entry.

I thought of storing with two tables, (1) of the keys for each entry and (2) of the values of specific keys for each entry, where entries share a common id field in both tables, but I am not sure how to pull entries as a key=>value pairs in sql with this sort of configuration.

Is there a better method?  If this is not possible in sqlite, is it possible in mysql?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for the [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

Alternatives are to create different tables for different types of entities, or to have a table with a column for every possible key and set the value to NULL for entities that don't have that key.

You might want to take a look at [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin)'s presentation [SQL Antipatterns](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back) where he covers some of the pros and cons of the EAV model and suggests possible alternatives. The relevant part starts from slide 16.

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Byers is right, this is the EAV model.  You should read [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/) before you go down that dark path.  It's a story of how this database design practically destroyed a company.

In a relational database, every row in a relation must include the same columns.  That's part of the definition for a *relation*.  This is true in SQLite, MySQL, or any other relational database.

Also see my presentation [Practical Object-Oriented Models in SQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql) or my book [SQL Antipatterns](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns), in which I show the problems caused by the EAV model.

If you need variable columns per entity, you need a non-relational database.  There are document-oriented databases like [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) that are catching on in popularity.

Or try [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) if you want an embeddable single-user solution like SQLite.